# In Delphi, how do you use BinToHex?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

Coming from LCL and Lazarus Pascal, I am trying to convert all my code to Delphi Pascal.

One line that is not working involves BinToHex:

```
function BinStr2Hex(S: AnsiString): AnsiString;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for i := 1 to Length(S)
    do Result := Result + AnsiLowerCase(BinToHex(Bytes(S[i]), 2));
end;
```

That throws an error of undeclared identifier Bytes (not sure how to write that as a declaration?) or do I have to use TBytes instead?

If I change it to TBytes, then I get a different error - There is no overloaded version of 'BixToHex' that can be called with these arguments.

How would I write this correctly in Delphi 10.4?

Thank you.

Comment: This works 100% in Lazarus Pascal. Does not work in Delphi.

Comment: I don't see how that is possible, as [there is no overloads](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/strutils/bintohex.html) that matches those parameters. Unless you are calling an overload that is not documented.

Comment: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/BinHexMethods_(Delphi)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no version of `Classes.BinToHex()`, in either [Delphi](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.BinToHex) or [FreePascal](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/strutils/bintohex.html), that takes 2 parameters, or has a return value.  Not only that, but the buffer size passed in is the *binary* bye count, not the *hex* character count, so it makes no sense to pass in `2` when hex-encoding a single `AnsiChar`.  So, the FreePascal code you have shown must be using a custom overload of `BinToHex()`.

In any case, any of the following overloads of `Classes.BinToHex()` can be used to hex-encode an `AnsiString` in Delphi:

```pascal
procedure BinToHex(Buffer: PAnsiChar; Text: PWideChar; BufSize: Integer); overload;
procedure BinToHex(Buffer: PAnsiChar; Text: PAnsiChar; BufSize: Integer); overload;
procedure BinToHex(var Buffer; Text: PWideChar; BufSize: Integer); overload; inline;
procedure BinToHex(var Buffer; Text: PAnsiChar; BufSize: Integer); overload; inline;
procedure BinToHex(Buffer: Pointer; Text: PWideChar; BufSize: Integer); overload; inline;
procedure BinToHex(Buffer: Pointer; Text: PAnsiChar; BufSize: Integer); overload; inline;
```

For example:

```pascal
uses
  System.Classes, System.AnsiStrings;

// Note: I would suggest using RawByeString instead for the input...
function BinStr2Hex(S: AnsiString{RawByteString}): AnsiString;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(S)*2);
  BinToHex(PAnsiChar(S), PAnsiChar(Result), Length(S));
  // or: BinToHex(S[1], PAnsiChar(Result), Length(S));
  // or: BinToHex(Pointer(S), PAnsiChar(Result), Length(S));
  Result := AnsiStrings.AnsiLowerCase(Result);
end;
```

Or, if you change the `Result` to `(Unicode)String`:

```pascal
uses
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils;

// Note: I would suggest using RawByeString instead for the input...
function BinStr2Hex(S: AnsiString{RawByteString}): String;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(S)*2);
  BinToHex(PAnsiChar(S), PChar(Result), Length(S));
  // or: BinToHex(S[1], PChar(Result), Length(S));
  // or: BinToHex(Pointer(S), PChar(Result), Length(S));
  Result := SysUtils.AnsiLowerCase(Result);
end;
```